# How to continue reading after using FindReaderSubmatchIndex

Tags: go

We use `regexp.FindReaderSubmatchIndex` to read a `bufio.Reader` until after a string.

E.g. we search for `foo` in `foobarboo`

What we encounter is that after the `FindReaderSubmatchIndex` call we can only read `boo` via consecutive `ReadRune` and `ReadByte` calls to the string.

Naively we would have expected to be able to read `barboo`.

Initially I thought that maybe it reads UTF-32 codepoints but from all I have investigated it seems like it operates on UTF-8. Thus I do not really understand what is going on or how to fix the behavior.

Briefly tried `bufio.UnreadRune` call and thus then I can at least read `rboo`.
Thus it seems like `FindReaderSubmatchIndex` always reads 3 codepoints too much.

Comment: Yeah, this is really strange. I tried a few permutations of the scenario you describe, and it always seems to be the case. It doesn't seem to be tied to the length of the pattern or the position of the match within the reader.

That method accepts a `RuneReader`, and runes are UTF-8 characters, so you're right about that.

Comment: Would your use case allow reading the bytes into a buffer first? The regexp package has a lot more options if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure why that doesn't work. With a pattern like `foo` I would expect that there is no need to read beyond an exact match, but those 3 bytes seem to be invariably read from the Reader regardless of position of the match in the stream or size of the pattern.

I can offer alternatives though. One approach would be to read the text into a buffer and parse it there, but I'm not sure if your use case would allow for that. If the input size won't allow for storage in memory then you'll need something more flexible.

The more flexible option would be something like a ring buffer that you can size according to your memory constraints that allows unread calls up to `UnreadRune(bufferSize)`. I've had a case in the past for something like this, so I put a [prototype](https://github.com/drognisep/runebuffer/blob/main/runebuffer.go) together that might be useful as a basis.